# Use of undefined constant SIGKILL - assumed 'SIGKILL'

Tags: php

Why do I get this one on some PHP distributions and not others..

```
posix_kill($row['pid'], SIGKILL);
```

Comment: To be fair, the marked question this is duplicating is actually a different question

Answer (score 2):

`SIGKILL` is a constant belonging to the [PCNTL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.constants.php). You may get undefined errors if your PHP version doesn't have the PCNTL extension installed or enabled.

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php) says "Process Control support in PHP is not enabled by default. You have to compile the CGI or CLI version of PHP with --enable-pcntl configuration option when compiling PHP to enable Process Control support."